# How would I go about masking specific $_GET variables as subfolders?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get

Say for example I have this: `http://domain.net/?page=admin&setting=system`

How could I make that look like `http://domain.net/admin/system/` using .htaccess while maintaining functionality of the `$_GET` variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, which would contain `/admin/system/` in your example. Now you can use the usual string manipulation functions to get the values.

```
$vars = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$page = $vars[1];
$setting = $vars[2];
```

To redirect all requests for inexistant files/directories to your index.php, use this in your .htaccess-file:

```
RewriteEngine on                     # Activates the rewrite engine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  # do not rewrite if folder exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  # do not rewrite if file exists
RewriteRule . index.php [L]          # otherwise, rewrite to index.php
```

Comment: However, /admin and /system are not actual directories. The file index.php is in the root of the website. I'm dynamically filling a specific div with content based on the ?page variable. I just find that /admin/system looks cleaner than a bunch of variables.

Comment: So you are actually looking for the content of a .htaccess-file?

Comment: Right. I am assuming that I can mask the get variables like a directory structure with .htaccess.

Comment: Would you be able to comment each line as to what they do? I'm still in the midst of learning how .htaccess files work. Kindly appreciated

Comment: So when /admin/system/ is navigated to, it loads index.php. And then using the REQUEST_URI as you stated, this would work.

Comment: Okay, cool. Now the challenge is to determine what is and isn't valid in the url to determine when to throw a 404. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried to add this to my .htaccess, but it caused the server to throw Error 500. Something is breaking somewhere in those few lines.

Comment: Maybe mod_rewrite is not loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do the job, notice the QSA rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(admin)/(system)/ index.php?page=$1&setting=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I've assumed a simple case though, few is parameterized.